# what is the best way to store btc for long-term?

Tags: bip32-hd-wallets, full-node, coldstorage

I am looking for a way to store btc for long-term.

Have been using airgapped hw wallet but I want to get rid of third party risk at all.

I do not want to use mnemonic anymore as I found that BIP39 is not supported by bitcoin core.

I am thinking of running my own full node+hd wallet+cold storage(dont want to store my seed on any electronic device as it can deteriorate).

I do not need to spend btc often as I hold it for long term. I just want to check if my balance is safe sometimes.

Can anyone recommend how I can achieve this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the question of utmost importance. The state of the art guidelines include generation, encryption and backup copies (on various media, e.g. paper, steel) of private keys (or keychain). Each situation is unique so individual approach must be taken to achieve the best result. Last but not least, human (imperfection/errors) is the weakest link so let's not forget to take care of oneself.

I'd suggest starting with an air-gapped PC with Bitcoin Core to generate keys and handwrite them (in encrypted form) on a paper. Improvements could be planned and implemented iteratively (e.g. another backup copy in steel as the next step).

Recommended reading:

- https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Key_Management_Cheat_Sheet.html
- https://www.lopp.net/bitcoin-information.html

Comment: wow thank you very much. the attached link is bit difficult to understand.. will go through it slowly. I appreciate it!

Comment: Seed Tool may be useful: https://bitcoiner.guide/seed/